Oracle APEX page designer not rendering properly
My organization has recently shifted the Oracle APEX infrastructure to AWS cloud.
After APEX installation was completed by the AWS team, i am seeing below page when trying to open the page designer.
It looks like some configuration settings are missing / Wrongly configured.
The worse part is no-one has the idea, what is wrong.
Can someone please provide any suggestions, or if you came across a similar issue, please suggest a workaround.


Looks like your javascript files are not accessible by the browser.

Agreed, extra hints may be present in browser console - and run apex_verify as Enrique suggests

Run this script file to get more info
apex_verify.sql 

This script it gets an output with the status of the APEX installation.
